# using environment variable to define elasticsearch index name in spring data Document annotation

Tags: java, spring-boot, elasticsearch

I have a spring-boot(v2.4.1) REST application which connects to an ElasticSearch index using spring-data-elasticsearch (v4.1.2) and elasticsearch client v7.9.3. I have no spring xml config files, all is done in annotations or code.

I would like to get the name of the index from an environment property.

The interaction with ElasticSearch is done using a `org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.ElasticsearchRestTemplate` which is created with a `RestHighLevelClient` instance.

The name of the index is not specified in the template or client but defined in the Document annotation of the entity:

```
@Document(indexName="cars", createIndex=false)
public class Car{
}
```

So instead of hardcoded "cars" value I want the value from a system property ES_INDEX_NAME.

Examples of failed attempts:

```
@Document(indexName="#{ systemProperties['es.index.name'] }", createIndex=false)
```

error: `EL1007E: Property or field 'systemProperties' cannot be found on null`

```
@Document(indexName="#{@environment.getProperty('es.index.name')}", createIndex=false)
```

error: `EL1057E: No bean resolver registered in the context to resolve access to bean 'environment'`

An attempt to get the environment variable in a component field and reference this bean in the annotation also failed:

```
@Component
public class ElasticSearchConfig {
    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ElasticSearchConfig.class);
 
    @Value("${es.index.name}")
    private String esIndexName;

    @PostConstruct
    public void afterInit() {
        LOGGER.info("Initialized ElasticSearchConfig: esIndexName="+esIndexName);
    }

    public String getEsIndexName() {
        return esIndexName;
    }

    public void setEsIndexName(String esIndexName) {
        this.esIndexName = esIndexName;
    }
}
```

The log prints the right value but:

```
@Document(indexName="#{@elasticSearchConfig.esIndexName}", createIndex=false)
```

error: `EL1057E: No bean resolver registered in the context to resolve access to bean 'elasticSearchConfig'`

```
@Document(indexName="#{elasticSearchConfig.esIndexName}", createIndex=false)
```

error: `EL1007E: Property or field 'elasticSearchConfig' cannot be found on null`

All these attempts are the result of searching on this issue but without any success.

Any more ideas how to solve this ?

Answer (score 0):

Don't know how but after another search attempt I've found this link: https://reflectoring.io/spring-boot-elasticsearch/

It explains how one can use `ElasticsearchRestTemplate` with separate index information.

In my document I changed the header annotation to asure it's not using this config:

```
@Document(indexName="notused", createIndex=false)
```

I added a new component which handles all interaction with the ElasticSearchTemplate:
(included all imports as I don't like answers without knowing the right classes to use)

```
import org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.ElasticsearchRestTemplate;
import org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.SearchHit;
import org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.mapping.IndexCoordinates;
import org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.query.IndexQueryBuilder;
import org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.query.NativeSearchQuery;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import not.your.business.Car;
import not.your.business.CarRef;

@Component
public class ElasticSearchService {
    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ElasticSearchService.class);
    
    @Value("${cars.elasticsearch.index.name}")
    private String esIndexName;

    @Autowired
    private RestHighLevelClient restHighLevelClient;
    
    private IndexCoordinates indexInfo;
    private ElasticsearchRestTemplate elasticsearchTemplate;

    @PostConstruct
    public void afterInit() {
        LOGGER.info("Initialized ElasticSearchConfig: esIndexName="+esIndexName);
        elasticsearchTemplate=new ElasticsearchRestTemplate(restHighLevelClient);
        indexInfo=IndexCoordinates.of(esIndexName);
    }

    public void deleteCar(Long carId)
    {
        elasticsearchTemplate.delete(new CarRef(carId),indexInfo);
    }
    public void save(Car car) {
        elasticsearchTemplate.index(new IndexQueryBuilder()
                .withId(car.getId().toString())
                .withObject(car).build(),indexInfo);
    }
    
    public <T> List<SearchHit<T>> search(NativeSearchQuery query,Class<T> resultType) {
        return elasticsearchTemplate.search(query,resultType,indexInfo).getSearchHits();
    }
}
```

The trick is in the extra parameter `IndexCoordinates` which holds the name of the index to use.

What I nice way to end the week...